# Filter And Move Data to different sheet Issue

Tags: vba, excel

The goal of my code is copy data from sheet "data" filtering column ABC by "Status Changed" string and then copy this column and the next 6 columns on right from this ABC column to sheet "parsing"
The problem here is that sometimes ABC is on column 1 and sometimes on column 2. So the code below wont work :/ because just looks in 1st column

Many thanks.

```
Sub Filter_and_move_data()
Dim LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("data")
    .Range("$A:$J").AutoFilter
    .Range("$A:$G").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Status Changed"
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("parsing").Range("A1")
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do ;)

```
Sub Filter_and_move_data()

With Worksheets("data")
    .Range("$A:$J").AutoFilter
    .Range("$A:$G").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Status Changed"
    .AutoFilter.Range.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("parsing").Range("A1")
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, my problem was different. I updated the topic. The column i need to filter sometimes is on first column, other times on 2nd .. and i need to copy this column and next 6columns on right of that column to different sheet.

Answer (score 0):

To copy only the data from rows A-G and not the whole row change this line

```
.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("parsing").Range("A1")
```

into this:

```
 .Range("A1:G" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("parsing").Range("A1")
```

Comment: sorry, my problem was different . Please see the first question again. thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know where your column ABC starts, you have two choices : either you detect range of column abc in your function, or you pass this range as argument. Then you have to set the correct field for your autofilter (you may also correct the range if needed) 
After that, you don't need to copy the entire row as you actually do, but only the next six columns. So you have to determine the range you want to copy, depending on the range you find for your column ABC.
Here is the code for the first solution :

```
Sub Filter_and_move_data()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim aCell As Range
Dim columnsToCopy As Long
columnsToCopy = 6
'determine where is located column abc between columns a and b (or whatever other range you need)
With Worksheets("data").Range("a1:b1")
    Set aCell = .Find("ABC", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Debug.Print aCell.Address & " // " & aCell.Column
End With

With Worksheets("data")
    .Range("$A:$G").AutoFilter field:=aCell.Column, Criteria1:="Status Changed"
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(Cells(1, aCell.Column), Cells(LastRow, aCell.Column + columnsToCopy)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("parsing").Range("A1")
End With  
End Sub
```